# Is it possible to adblock while on mobile data?

Tags: browser, mobile-data, mobile-network, adblock-plus

I can use AdBlock Plus to block ads on wifi. Is there a way to do it while on mobile data? I'd like to use it in Chrome, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It used to work on older android versions. I'm not sure about newer android versions..

Basically it involves changing the active mobile network APN to add proxy and port that is suggested by AdBlock Plus.

**Proxy:** `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
**Port:** `2020` or what AdBlock notifies in status bar.

Save the APN and run AdBlock Plus to see the changes. And if AdBlock Plus isn't running after changing APN, you may not be able to browse through mobile data, complaining about proxy server. Revert APN changes to revert.

If you try the above method, please post the results. And make sure the adblock plus active filter subscription has the ability to block what you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Chrome on lollipop and downloaded ab+, it suggested easy list filter so I didn't add more. Created an alternate mobile nw on phone since t-mobile blocked editing the main entry. I added localhost and proxy 2020, switched to the new entry,  and social media bar was gone on pages even without a reboot.  If your provider doesn't whine about root that would be easier (my carrier whines about everything but that's another discussion).  Too early to tell if any downside but for now i can finally read text on a page